# Stop eventOverlap when external event drop in fullcalendar

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I want to stop eventOverlapping, when external event drop in jquery fullcalendar.
My event drop code is below:

```
drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped
            eventID += 1;
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            copiedEventObject.id = eventID;
            // render the event on the calendar
            $("calendarformyabsence").fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

`overlap` is an [event](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) property. [`eventOverlap`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventOverlap/) is a callback function that you can use to dynamically allow/disallow overlapping.

You likely want `overlap`.

To set it for an external event, you add it as a data attribute. With jQuery that looks like:

```
$('#external-event').data('event', {
    overlap: false,
    // and any other options
    title: "event"
});
```

Here's an example **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/xkmx8sgp/6/)** using similar code to the [FC demo page](http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.2.6/demos/external-dragging.html).